# jQuery Add Class to single instance

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, preventdefault, toggleclass

I have tried a couple different configurations of this code without success:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".open-drawer").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
 $(".drawer-out").toggleClass("opencan");
 });
```

})

The above code will open and close the drawer, only there are 10 instances of a.open-drawer on the page, when any of them are clicked, they all open.

I tried removeClass but without any luck...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".open-drawer").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
 $(".drawer-out").removeClass("opencan");
 this.addClass("opencan")
 });
```

})

The code examples I saw quite a bit different from my original code, any love is super appreciated.

This is the HTML for the events that repeat on the page the link for the open drawer is 12 lines from the bottom, the drawer html is just beneath it.

```
<div class="grid-100 parent-grid vatx-eventlist">
<div class="grid-30 mobile-grid-100">
    <span style="float:left; width: 150px;margin-right:15px;">#_EVENTIMAGE</span>
</div>
<div id="mainevent" class="grid-70 mobile-grid-100">
    <span class="eventdate"> #_{l, F j} <br /></span>
    <h2><a href="#_EVENTURL">#_EVENTNAME</a></h2>   
    <span>Doors Open: #_ATT{Doors Open:} </span><br />
    <span>Tickets: #_ATT{ Tickets price $}</span><br />
    <span>Age: #_ATT{Age restrictions?} <!-- <a href="#_ATT{rsvp link}">RSVP</a> --></span><br/>
    <span id="#_ATT{custom field 1 yes or no?}">#_ATT{Custom Field 1:} </span><br />
    <span id="#_ATT{custom field 2 yes or no?}">#_ATT{Custom Field 2:} </span><br />
    <a class="grid-15 tablet-grid-30 mobile-grid-30 facebook txt-align-center" href="http://facebook.com/vulcanatx" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a class="grid-15 tablet-grid-30 mobile-grid-30 instagram txt-align-center" href="http://instagram.com/vulcanatx" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
<a class="grid-15 tablet-grid-30 mobile-grid-30 twitter txt-align-center" href="http://twitter.com/vulcanatx" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <div class="event-buttons grid-35 mobile-grid-100 txt-align-right">
        <a class="event-btn gold-button" id="#_ATT{Tickets yes or no ?}" href="#_ATT{Ticket URL  please include http://}" target="_blank" />Buy Tickets</a><br />
        <a class="event-btn table-button" href="#">Table Service</a>
        <br />
        <a id="open-drawer" class="open-drawer event-btn more-button" href="#">More</a>
    </div>  

</div>
<div class="grid-100 drawer-out">
    <div class="drawer">
        <div class="container">
            <span>Description:</span>#_EVENTNOTES<br /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using this on?

Comment: code added, thanks for taking a look.  #_Etc are shortcodes from a WordPess plugin that output text.

Answer (score 0):

It will toggle class only for clicked element

```
$(".open-drawer").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("opencan");
});
```

But in your example you are trying to toggle classes for different elements. If you need to add class for related element(not for clicked), it will be another code. Could you post your html?

Comment: HTML added to my original question, thanks for taking a look Alexey

Comment: this adds "opencan" to .open-drawer, and successfully does this one at a time, but I'm trying to add the class "opencan" to a div with a class of ".drawer-out"

Comment: You should put your `.open-drawer` and `.drawer-out` to one container or add `id` or some other attributes to indicate a relation